# Using Cursor with setMultiChoiceItems in Alert dialog

Tags: android

I want to display a multichoice list in an alert dialog box. If I'm using an array to store the list of items, then it is working fine :

```
d.setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.items,
                    new boolean[]{false, true, false, true, false, false, false},
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton,
                                boolean isChecked) {

                            /* User clicked on a check box do some stuff */
                        }
                    })
```

But in my case, the item list is dynamic, which I'm geting from a database. The database keeps on updating its contents and hence the list is also updating at a fixed interval of time.
So, instead of using an array I would like to use a cursor in the argument of setMultiChoiceItems.
Can anyone please tell me how to do it....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use another version of `setMultiChoiceItems()`, the one that takes a `Cursor` as a parameter. You also give it the name of the columns in the result set that represent the label and the boolean checkbox setting.

Answer (score 0):

we in JohnBryce Jerusalem, course id 5124 solved this problem by implementing it ourselves as follows:

```
final Map<Long,Boolean> selectedContactsMap = new HashMap<Long,Boolean>();

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) 
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Share link");
    View selectContactView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_select_layout, null);
    builder.setView(selectContactView);

    ListView contactsListView = (ListView)selectContactView.findViewById(R.id.selectContactListView);

    CursorAdapter adapter = new CursorAdapter(this, cursor, true)
    {

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context arg1, Cursor cursor) 
        {
            final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID));
            final String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            TextView displayNameTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.displayNameTextView);
            final CheckBox selectContactCheckBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.selectContactCheckBox);

            displayNameTextView.setText(displayName);

            boolean isChecked = selectedContactsMap.containsKey(id)?
                        selectedContactsMap.get(id):false;

            selectContactCheckBox.setChecked(isChecked);

            selectContactCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    boolean isChecked = selectContactCheckBox.isChecked();
                    if(!isChecked && selectedContactsMap.containsKey(id))
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Remove id: "+id+": "+displayName);
                        selectedContactsMap.remove(id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Select id: "+id+": "+displayName+" : "+isChecked);
                        selectedContactsMap.put(id, isChecked);
                    }   
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) 
        {
            View selectContactItemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_select_item_layout, null);
            return selectContactItemView;
        }

    };

    contactsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) 
        {
            WebViewerFragment webViewerFrag = (WebViewerFragment)
                    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.web_viewer_fragment);

            String currentLink = null;
            if (webViewerFrag != null) 
            {
                currentLink = webViewerFrag.getCurrentLink();
                long _id = (Long)view.getTag();
                share(_id, currentLink);

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No link is found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            shareDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    contactsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    builder.setView(selectContactView);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Share!", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,":-(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    shareDialog = builder.create();



}
```